# Нужно ли тире в нижеследующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

«Гостиница «Парус» – одна из тех, куда заселили жителей Севера».

Нужно ли тире перед «одна»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Гостиница «Парус» – одна из тех** [гостиниц], **куда заселили жителей Севера.***

В данном случае я бы ориентировался на интонацию (после ***«Паруса»*** следует явная пауза) и на следующее [**правило**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172):

> Существует несколько случаев, когда для интонационно-логического членения фразы между подлежащим и сказуемым необходимо поставить тире.
> <...>
> ...если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены...
> <...>
> существительным и словосочетанием с числительным...

Да, слово ***одна*** здесь выступает не в роли числительного, а в роли прилагательного [см. [**ОДИН**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD&all=x), **II. *в знач. прил.* 4.** Определённый (из числа однородных лиц, предметов, явлений)]. Но это не отменяет тире перед предложным сочетанием ***одна из тех***.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

*«Служебный роман» ― один из тех фильмов, которые хочется смотреть снова и снова...* [Форум: рецензии на фильм «Службный роман» (2006-2010)]

*Как бы то ни было, эта идея ― одна из тех, что продолжают претендовать на серьезное изменение наших устоявшихся представлений.* [Предчувствие «большого слома» // «Знание - сила», 1997]

*Владимир Рафаилович ― один из тех наших австраловедов, которые изучают аборигенскую жизнь...* [Д. А. Гранин. Месяц вверх ногами (1966)]

Comment: Александр, откройте тайну: почему один ― это прилагательное. А если трое из нас, то трое ― тоже прилагательное? :)

Comment: @Sharon Это не прилагательное, но имеет **значение** прилагательного, является определением (какой?). Ну так в словаре написано, в моей ссылке под цифрой **II**, пункт **4.** Оно вроде и не числительное в строгом понимании. *Поселился здесь одним из первых. Один из стульев сломан*.

Comment: Одна из тех гостиниц, куда... Здесь тех – местоименное прилагательное. Одна из тех, куда... Вроде бы указательное местоимение здесь имеет предметное значение, используется в значении существительного. Кустова в сочетании "один из нас" называет "один" числительным.

Comment: Столько нюансов... Лучше бы не лез в эту статью про ОДИН :)) – числительное и всё. О тех понятно, но мы же не о нем. В статье много пунктов под римской двойкой, и везде там Один отвечает на вопрос какой?, тяготеет к определению. В нашем случае мы рассматриваем сказуемое, составное, неделимое, да. Но всё равно: Гостиница какая? – одна из тех. Получаем числительно-местоименно-определительское сказуемое. :)

Comment: Это точно, без надобности лучше не углубляться (по себе знаю),  Прицепится кто-нибудь...:)  Так что лучше забудем.  Для справок: Я думаю, что здесь и подлежащее,  и сказуемое – это предметы.  Ведь определительное придаточное определяет предмет,  а если у нас местоименно-определительное придаточное, то в роли предмета-существительного выступает местоимение (в нашем случае неделимое сочетание). И лучше его не делить... :)

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: ***Гостиница «ПАрус» – одна из тех, куда заселили жителей Севера.***

С точки зрения интонации, в предложении явно присутствует **пауза,** которую можно обозначить только **тире**.

**По правилам Розенталя** тире ставится, если сказуемое выражено фразеологическим оборотом, то есть устойчивым сочетанием. В данном случае ***одна из тех*** – это нечленимое словосочетание, которое в предложении является сказуемым. В состав сочетания входит указательное  местоимение.
Предложение сложноподчиненное с придаточным определительным. Местоименная пара (из тех – куда).